# OnItemClickListener doesn't work , OnItemClick is not called

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I'm trying to make a Toast message whenever I click an item from the list, For some reason when I click the item nothing happens,

I hope you can help me, thanks.

**ProductList.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.SparseBooleanArray;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;


public class ProductList extends AppCompatActivity {


    private List<myProductsView> myProducts_types = new ArrayList<myProductsView>();
    ArrayAdapter<myProductsView> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.pop_productlist);

        //Button btnDel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDel);
        //adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,list);
        populateProductsList();
        populateListView();


    }

    private void populateProductsList() {
        myProducts_types.add(new myProductsView("aaa", "aaa", 1111, 12.90, R.drawable.cereal, 1));
        myProducts_types.add(new myProductsView("aaa", "aaaaaa ", 1112, 10.90, R.drawable.cereal, 2));
        myProducts_types.add(new myProductsView("aaa", "aaa", 1112, 30.00, R.drawable.cereal, 1));
        myProducts_types.add(new myProductsView("aaa", "aaa", 1112, 20.00, R.drawable.cereal, 3));

    }

    private void populateListView() {
        adapter = new MyListAdapter();
        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.product_list);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                System.out.println("BLALBALBLALBLABLAL");
                Toast.makeText(ProductList.this, "BLA", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            }
        });

    }
    public void StartCalck(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(ProductList.this, SplitBuying.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<myProductsView>{



        public MyListAdapter(){
            super(ProductList.this, R.layout.pop_productlist, myProducts_types);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            //make sure we have a view to work with(may have been given null
            View itemView = convertView;

            if(itemView == null){
                itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.product_item_view, parent, false);
            }
            //we need to populate the list
            //find the product to work with
            myProductsView currentProduct = myProducts_types.get(position);

            //fill the view
            CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_checkBox);
            checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Toast.makeText(ProductList.this,"BLA",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                }
            });

            TextView productname = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_name);
            productname.setText(currentProduct.getProductName());

            EditText quantity = (EditText)itemView.findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
            quantity.setText(String.valueOf(currentProduct.getQuantity()));





            return itemView;
        }




    }






}
```

**product_item_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="7dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_minus"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:text="-" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edit_text"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:text="0" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_plus"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:text="+" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Text"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/product_name"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/product_checkBox"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/product_checkBox" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:id="@+id/product_checkBox" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**pop_productlist.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/ightwall"
    android:id="@+id/drawerlayout">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="הרשימה שלי"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="30dp" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">




    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/product_list"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ChooseStore"
            >
        </ListView>

    </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/CalckButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/calckButton"
            android:onClick="StartCalck"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnDel"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:text="@string/lblBtnDel"
            />



    </LinearLayout>




    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="#D5D4D4"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/mylist"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/createlist_mylist"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:maxHeight="90dp"
            android:maxWidth="90dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/freeadd"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/createlist_freetext"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:maxHeight="90dp"
            android:maxWidth="90dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />



        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/favproductadd"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/createlist_favproduct"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:maxHeight="90dp"
            android:maxWidth="90dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />



    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to call `.show()` on your toast.

change

```
Toast.makeText(ProductList.this, "BLA", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
```

to

```
Toast.makeText(ProductList.this, "BLA", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```